# Try/Catch, or doing the exception handling without changing the method header

Tags: java, java-io

I am writing a simple program, it writes "I love Java" 300 times to a text file, and I have it working as shown.

```
public class PrintLines {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{    
         java.io.File file = new java.io.File("myFile.txt");
         java.io.PrintWriter output = new java.io.PrintWriter(file);        
         int count = 1;
         while (count <= 300) {
             output.println(count + " I love Java!");
             count++;           
         }
         output.close();
    }
}
```

What I am unsure about, and have been trying to figure out on several webpages and the text book I use for class, is how do I do a try/catch block for this code and still create the file?  It works, as I said, but I have to do it without the **throws Exception** in there.  Can't find a decent webpage which gives newbie answers for beginning programmers like me.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/charstreams.html. Note that if you can't handle the IOException, you should let your method throw it. You should use a finally block to close the writer, though.

Comment: I don't think you want your main to ever throw an exception. Throwing an exception means that what ever is calling that method will have to catch it, or throw it. Since main is your entry point, there's no where that you can catch it in this program.

Comment: ... except the UncaughtExceptionHandler, which by default prints a nice stack trace to `System.err`. For simple programs intended for a technically literate audience, that can be sufficient.

Comment: Does nobody want to check if writing the file actually worked? Didn't think so.

Comment: Oh it worked.  I did it 3 times before I got stuck with how to do the exception handling without it in the header.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code should look similar to this.
The *EXCEPTION* should be IOException, I think.

```
public class PrintLines {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        java.io.File file;
        java.io.PrintWriter output = null;
        try{
            file = new java.io.File("myFile.txt");
            output = new java.io.PrintWriter(file);
            int count = 1;
            while (count <= 300) {
                output.println(count + " I love Java!");
                count++;

           }
           output.close();
       } catch(*EXCEPTION*) {
       //Handle Exception
       } finally {
          if(output!=null) {
           output.close();
          }
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think there's also be a FileNotFoundException you have to catch as well. You'll add another catch(FileNotFoundException) {} block between the first catch listed in the code sample and the finally block.

Comment: Actually the IOException will take care of that, but if you want to be more explicit to how you handle the exceptions then you can separate them out.

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't remember if 1 inherited from the other or if there was no relation.

Comment: Side Note:
You can 'import java.io.*' so you do not have to be as explicit with file and Printwriter

Comment: Not going to compile with more sensible streams. Can I suggest not mixing `catch` and `finally`. Do the resource acquisition thing as a completely separate thing **without `null`**.

Comment: @Tom, how would you code that?

I figured it out thanks to you Rcunn.

public class PrintLines {
    public static void main(String[] args){
  java.io.File file;
  java.io.PrintWriter output = null;

         try {
    file = new java.io.File("myFileTwo.txt");
    output = new java.io.PrintWriter(file);
           int count = 1;
           while (count <= 300) {
              output.println(count + " I love Java!");
              count++;
     }
          }
         catch (java.io.IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
   }
   finally {
    if (output != null) output.close();
   }
  }
 }

Answer (score 1):

The [Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) are intended for people new to Java, and explain these things quite well. In particular, the [essential classes trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/index.html) describes exceptions and I/O in detail. And yes, the code examples for I/O demonstrate correct exception handling, too.

Comment: Yes, and I look at them but it doesn't make sense to me that way.  My way of learning unfortunately requires a little more explanation sometimes, with examples.

Answer (score 0):

It would look something like this -

```
public class PrintLines {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        java.io.File file = new java.io.File("myFile.txt");
        java.io.PrintWriter output = null;
        try {
            output = new java.io.PrintWriter(file);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
        int count = 1;
        while (count <= 300) {
            output.println(count + " I love Java!");
            count++;
        }
        output.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: NullPointerException is not generally preferable to FileNotFoundException :)

Comment: of course this is just an example to use try catch block. The throws Exception in this case is for FileNotFoundException.

Comment: Its an incorrect example of try catch block ;) where are you throwing FileNotFoundException ?

Comment: @Bhavana: you didn't understand. Your code is guaranteed to throw a NullPointerException if the PrintWriter can't be created (because the file is read-only, for example). And you don't close it in a finally block. In short, your example is an example of what should not be done.

Answer (score 0):

In Java exceptions are handled with a `try` and `catch` block. If you state that your method throws Exception you are having the exception handled at a higher level. If you want to handle it you have to write your code in a try and catch block. There are also more than one type of exception you can catch.

```
public class PrintLines {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        java.io.File file;
        java.io.PrintWriter output;
        try {
           file = new java.io.File("myFile.txt");
           output = new java.io.PrintWriter(file);
           int count = 1;
           while (count <= 300) {
               output.println(count + " I love Java!");
               count++;
           }
       } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {// If the file does not exist
             e.printStackTrace();// Prints the error
       } catch(IOException e) {//any other io error
             e.printStackTrace();// Prints the error
       } finally {
            if(output!=null){
               output.close();
            }
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: why are you closing output twice ?

Comment: I don't think that compiles. I also suggest not mixing `catch` with `finally` and certainly avoiding the `null`s.

Comment: i personally never use finally in my own code, but that's how it is suggested in the Orical tutorials.

Comment: if you have a better way, please enlighten me or us.  I want to see how this can be done simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Because a comment is too short:

```
public class PrintLines {
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        java.io.File file = new java.io.File("myFile.txt");
        try {
            final java.io.PrintWriter output = new java.io.PrintWriter(file);
            try {
                int count = 1;
                while (count <= 300) {
                    output.println(count + " I love Java!");
                    count++;           
                }
            } finally {
                output.close();
            }
            if (output.checkError()) {
                System.err.println("Failed to write file correctly.");
                System.exit(1);
                return;
            }
        } catch (java.io.FileNotFoundException exc) {
            System.err.println("Failed to write file correctly.");
            System.exit(1);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

It's not nice code. We keep going even if there is a problem with the output, and we *implicitly* pick up whatever character encoding happens to be set as the default at the time.

```
// imports elided

public class PrintLines {
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        File file = new File("myFile.txt");
        try (OutputStream rawOut = new FileOutputStream{file);
            BuffereWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                rawOut, java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8
            ));
            int count = 1;
            while (count <= 300) {
                out.write(count + " I love Java!");
                out.newLine();
                count++;           
            }
            out.flush();
        } catch (java.io.IOException exc) {
            System.err.println("Failed to write file correctly.");
            System.exit(1);
            return;
        }
    }
}o
```

I've used the Java SE 7 new try statement. Note that the exception thrown by the resource allocation and release are caught in the `catch` block, and is the *opposite* behaviour than seen with a Java SE 6 `try-catch-finally`.